# A native webextension does not work in Firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions, web-extension

The native app described [here](https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/blob/main/native-messaging/) is not working for me, errors like:

```
Reading manifest: Warning processing XXX: An unexpected property was found in the WebExtension manifest.
```

Problematic XXX fields: `allowed_extensions, type, path`

How can I make it work?

I tried to import it via `about:debugging` (Temp project, in a folder I selected the manifest file)
I was expecting no warnings whatsoever. And that the extension does work.

Comment: Sounds like you've used the wrong folder. Load the addon folder not the app.

Comment: I cannot select a folder to load as addon, I can only select the `manifest.json` file in that folder to load. Which I did. Not working.

Comment: manifest.json doesn't have allowed_extensions, type, path. Only the the wrong folder has them in ping_pong.json. Try re-downloading, maybe your copy is corrupted.